# Synaptics and display issue

Tags: display, touchpad, 17.04, synaptics

I'm facing this issue where synaptics shows up as a display for me each time I start my laptop.

All I've got right now is screenshots but don't know where to look to find more logs related to this issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I start my laptop, my touchpad is extremely sensitive and I have two displays when I go to the displays in settings. The mouse pointer also keeps running off to the right side of the screen.

I cannot actually see the display named "synaptics" (in the right on the screenshot).

I then toggle the synaptics display to off and my screen adjusts the only one display, but the touchpad is still too sensitive and I can see the synaptics display in the display settings screen (2nd screenshot)

I again toggle the synaptics display to on, then wait a few seconds, the screen flashes, then I just have one display in the display settings, the touchpad sensitivity issue is fixed and the pointer doesn't run off to the right side. (3rd screenshot)

Any ideas what I can do to fix the issue on startup? Or where in the logs can I find more information?

I've checked syslog and the xorg log and haven't been able to find any relevant messages.

Has anyone faced this issue before.

Running Ubuntu 17.04 on a Dell Latitude E7470 with an ALPS touchpad and pointer stick. Please leave me a message in the comments if you want more info about the hardware (and also, how I can get that info)

Output for `xinput  -list`

`⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick             id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 17.04 have another settings app, just click Windows key and type "set" and start the other settings app, maybe will find more options...

About the high sensitive, should setup at settings/wacom.

About the pointer getting off, is because Ubuntu sums every display into one bigger virtual desktop, which is fixed if all other displays are turn off. To see the desktop size, at terminal "xrandr" and read the first line, then turn other displays off and "xrandr" gives the right desktop size...

Comment: No luck with the other settings manager. :(